# Gesture detector not detecting the video player screen as I put video player is its child

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a video player I want to access the video players screen to add some functionality on onTap function but Gesturedetector is not detecting the screen but if I put container as its child it detects container.

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => social(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.black,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 200),
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

if I put this code is such a way it do not access Chewie widget

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => social(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Wrap your Video Player in IgnorePointer()
2. behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque add this property to your Gesture Detector,

   ```
      GestureDetector(
                               behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                               onTap: () {
                                 Utils.launchURL(PersonalData.email);
                               },
                               child: IgnorePointer(

                                 fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                 child: SizedBox(
                                   height:
                                       MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                                   width:
                                       MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
                                   child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                                 ),
                               ))),
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`GestureDetector` will only detect those clicks which are taking place on it `child`.

In first example, you provided a `Container` with `height: 200`, that means `200` logical pixel is the height where you can receive clicks.

In second case, your widget `Chewie` may not have desired `width` or `height` not allowing `GestureDetector` to receive clicks.

The solution would be to use following as child of `GestureDetector`.

```
SizedBox.expand(
  child: Chewie(...)
)
```

Comment: not working in this way too. not detecting the  video player screen

Answer (score 0):

GestureDetector(
behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,

```
                  onDoubleTap: (){
                    print('lllllllll');
                    setState(() {
                      isShowUser = !isShowUser;
                    });
                  },

                  )
```

Comment: You don't have to use  onTap, because it will show only the controllers. I know this is coming very late, but hope it will help someone. Thanks